# Pass id's to url on a count being diplayed in table

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I have a function in which I am returning a count which when displayed is clickable. When clicked on this count the page redirects to listing of the of users with their details. The count displayed has link to the information page with `id`'s of the users passed in URL. I am not getting the result as the link shows only one user id instead of two(as per database) or some irrelevant `id`'s. Where I am missing the thing, any help will be highly appreciated.

function for displaying count,

```
  function clearedmodule()
  {
   $id= '';
   $res =   mysql_query("SELECT id from tbl_users WHERE status= 1 AND type = 3 ");

        while($row  =   mysql_fetch_array($res))

        {
        $query =  mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tbl_user_quiz  GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT module_id) = '".$this->userQuestionModules()."'  AND SUM(cleared) = 0 ");
       while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
       {
           foreach($row1 as $cname => $id)
           {
            $id     .=  $row['id'].',';
           }

       }

    }
        return substr($id, 0, -1);

  }
```

Now the `<td>` where the count is being displayed,

```
     <td>Not Cleared</td>

     <td>
      <?php 

        $ids = $rep->clearedmodule();

        $ids    =   explode(",",$ids) ;

      $linkId = $rep->clearedmodule();

            if($linkId)

      {   ?>
       <a href="reportNotCleared.php?Userid=<?php echo $linkId ; ?>"><?php echo count($ids); ?></a>

    <?php 

     } 
     else{
    echo "0";
 }
?> </a></td>
```

Using above, the URL I am getting is

`reportNotCleared.php?Userid=10131183` where `1013` is right id , `1183` is not at all correct and I want them to be comma separated.

Comment: The link looks fine.  Are you able to show the string returned from the clearedmodule() function.  Please post in your original quesiton.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I have edited the question. please take a look. Currently using the above `$query` query, I have 2 records in database `1013` and `1012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query is the only query you needed.  Just remove all the loops except the middle one and you should be good to go!

```
function clearedmodule() {

$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tbl_user_quiz GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT module_id) = '".$this->userQuestionModules()."' AND SUM(cleared) = 0 ");

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

$id .= $row1['user_id'] . ',';

}

return substr($id, 0, -1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern. But I am afraid, changing this gives out 336 counts, which is not possible.

Comment: Thats because your looping through a bunch of stuff and $row['id] is blank but your still adding a comma.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried your updated answer but still no luck . The problem still same

Comment: Are you using $row or $row1 for the $id values?

Comment: $row for $id values.which is from the first query `$result`

Comment: are you sure that does not make sense.

Comment: Then what it should be ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170893/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-ansh).

Comment: Wonderful explaination. Keep up the good work. Many thanks @Joseph_J

Comment: Hey no problem, Cheers:)